# AVPlayer not showing video in iOS7, working fine on iOS8 and iOS9

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, avplayer

This is my code,

```
@interface ViewController ()
{
    AVPlayer *avPlayer;
}
@end

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    UIView *containerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    NSString *filepath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"TestVideo" ofType:@"mp4"];
    AVAsset *asset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filepath]];
    AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithAsset:asset];
    avPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
    AVPlayerLayer *avPlayerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:avPlayer];

    avPlayerLayer.frame = self.view.frame;
    [containerView.layer addSublayer:avPlayerLayer];
    [self.view addSubview:containerView];
    [avPlayer play];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That really shouldn't work on any iOS version as

```
AVPlayer *avPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
```

is going out of scope and being deallocated at the end of `viewDidAppear`.

You should assign the `AVPlayer` to a class member variable, to stop this happening.

Otherwise there may be a problem with the video file.

Comment: Thanks but updated code also didn't work for me. (please see update)

Comment: I guess it is iOS7 specific issue as it's working fine on iOS8 and 9.

Comment: Do you have a URL to the problem file?

Comment: It is my file path : `/Users/zaid.pathan/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/C595D53B-EC6E-4BC2-9‌​59D-B6FDDC8CA7BD/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/0E569CF4-E153-46E1-AA86-D2107‌​45287A9/AVPlayerTestiOS7.app/TestVideo.mp4`

Comment: Would you like to suggest anything else?

Comment: Share the file, maybe that's where the problem is

Comment: Did you mean video file? , If yes then why it's working on iOS8 and +?

Comment: You were right, changing video file worked for me. :-)
Please update your answer so that I can accept it. (Don't know why that video was problematic)

Comment: Hi Rhythmic any chance you know why AVPlayer sometimes plays audio but not video? Already eliminated frame, main thread, and ready status as causes. Seems related to timing since waiting 5-10 seconds to play video fixes the issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41052277/avplayer-blank-video-playing-sound-but-no-video/41053799#41053799

Answer (score 0):

Your AVPlayer item needs a strong reference as it sets to nil automatically

Please change

```
@interface ViewController ()

{
    AVPlayer *avPlayer;
}
@end
```

to this

```
@interface ViewController ()  
@property (strong, nonatomic) AVPlayer *avPlayer;
@end
```

and change all `avPlayer` reference to `self.avPlayer`
I hope this helps.

Comment: No, it didn't help me. I guess it is iOS7 specific issue as it's working fine on iOS8 and 9.

Comment: Would you like to suggest anything else?